# How to analyse performance issue on apache web server?

Tags: apache-2.2, performance, performance-monitoring

My web application is suffering form the performance issues. like delay in response and all,

I would like you to give me some pointer where I can learn about analyzing performance issues on apache server.

Update :
One good suggestion I am going to implement is to add caching support for web server. I am going to do that. Will see what performance improves after this support is added.

Thanks.

Comment: Please be more specific. Is this problem present on your development box with only a handful of traffic, or is the problem only occurring under high-traffic production servers? What kind of application you have? And what's the environment? LAMP server?

Comment: Question is vague, badly worded, missing a lot of detail about the problem, what you have done already to try and solve it, what the actual metrics are, what your expectations are....

Comment: Thanks for down voting, But this is all i could have understand form the requirement, I am told to study why my application is responding slow. that all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a combination of apache benchmark ab (launched in a client against the server) and sar (launched on the client at the same time) would do the trick, search for it on the internet, you'll find plenty of stuff.

Comment: Sar is Specific Absorption Rate? right?

Comment: On unix like systems [sar](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sar) is used to produce reports based on information that is collected by [sadc](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sadc). These can be used to help track down performance issues.

Answer (score 2):

I believe [Apache Performance Tuning](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/perf-tuning.html) is the best place to start.

Comment: +1 because despite it generally being frowned on here I always love an RTFM answer. :)