# Apache 2.2.16 with mod_php on Debian Squeeze CPU high load

Tags: apache-2.2, php, central-processing-unit, mod-php

Configuration:

CPU 16 cores 
14 GB RAM
Apache 2.2.16
PHP 5.3.3-7 with enabled APC

Apache mpm config:

StartServers          50
    MinSpareServers       50
    MaxSpareServers      256
    MaxClients          256
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0

With about 20-30 simultaneous connections apache requests take a lot of time, because CPU raised to 100%

mod_stat shows RANDOMLY apache processes and random scripts, that use more than 5% cpu

php applications worked greate with smaller hardware configuration and ths situation seems strange.

Comment: So what? What should we say beside "that's life"? We can't look into your application remotely and say you have a problem in line 210 up to line 213. Or have a DNS server issue due to entering the wrong DNS forwarders. Or your kernel version is way too old.

Comment: I understand it. I only want to know, how i can trace it and localize the problem to solve it.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/180519/how-to-analyse-performance-issue-on-apache-web-server and all the related question on that question.